WebApplicationFactory failing to replace registrations in Background Service
I have run into an issue when trying to integration test a background service that listens to messages from RabbitMq. The issue is, after the first test runs, the subsequent test still has the same registration as the previous one.
I have created a project to illustrate the issue.
[Fact]
        public async Task FirstTest1()
        {
            await SetupRabbitMq();

            _fixture.BuildConsumerHttpClient((service) =>
            {
                service.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IMessage, MessageTest1>());
                return true;
            });

            BasicPublish(new PublicationAddress(_rabbitMqClientConsumerConfiguration.ExchangeType, _rabbitMqClientConsumerConfiguration.LoggingExchangeName, string.Empty), "MessageTest1"u8.ToArray());
        }


        [Fact]
        public async Task SecondTest2()
        {
            await SetupRabbitMq();

            _fixture.BuildConsumerHttpClient((service) =>
            {
                service.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IMessage, MessageTest2>());

                return true;
            });

            BasicPublish(new PublicationAddress(_rabbitMqClientConsumerConfiguration.ExchangeType, _rabbitMqClientConsumerConfiguration.LoggingExchangeName, string.Empty), "MessageTest2"u8.ToArray());
        }

public class MessageTest1 : IMessage
{
    public string Message => "MessageTest1";
}
public class MessageTest2 : IMessage
{
    public string Message => "MessageTest2";
}

Here we set the service for each test to be MessageTest1 and MessageTest2 respectively along with the message that is sent from each test. Yet, as we can see in the Service, while it is receiving the message string "MessageTest2", the service registered is MessageTest1.

Full project illustrating the issue.
https://github.com/Pastafarian/WebApplicationFactoryBugIssue
What's odd is even when I verify that the Background service is disposed, it appears the old version is still being used.
Any help gladly received.
